# Why can't dictionary keys be made to be cells?

Tags: vba, excel

I was having trouble with more complicated code and me not understanding dictionaries fully yet, so I built a really basic, simple, test sheet to figure out how they work.  Only three entries, reading "first", "do", and "alpha", across the top of columns a-c (goal was to eventually make sure I understood nested dictionaries, though this question doesn't get into that anyway).

The code was:

```
Sub testing()

Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary

dict.Add Key:=Cells(1, 1), Item:=Cells(1, 2)
MsgBox dict(Cells(1, 1))

End Sub
```

This did not work.  But when I added a variable `temp = Cells(1, 1)` and used that in place of `Cells(1, 1)` wherever it appeared, it worked.

Why can't the key be a cell?  Can someone help me understand what the difference between

```
dict.Add Key:=Cells(1, 1), Item:=(1, 2)
```

and

```
temp = Cells(1, 1)

dict.Add Key:=temp, Item:=(1, 2)
```

is?  The item can be a cell, just not the key?

Comment: put `.value` at the end of both Cells(1,1)

Comment: yes, dictionary is very accommodating when storing the data. Without `Value` its stores the range object.

Comment: Oh!  I had not heard of this function.  So `.value` returns a string of whatever is in the thing `.value` is attached to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* use objects as both keys and values (including the ranges returned by `.Cells`), as this code demonstrates:

```
Public Sub Example()
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    dict.Add Sheet1.Cells(1, 1), Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)
    dict.Add Sheet1.Cells(1, 2), Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)

    Dim x As Variant
    For Each x In dict.Keys
        Debug.Print TypeName(x) 'Prints Range
    Next

    For Each x In dict.Items
        Debug.Print TypeName(x) 'Prints Range
    Next
End Sub
```

In fact, your code above "works" - you're just not seeing what you expect in your `MsgBox`. On this line of code...

```
MsgBox dict(Cells(1, 1))
```

...the first parameter to `MsgBox` is a `Variant`, but it ultimately needs to be able to display a `String`.  If it receives an object as a parameter, it calls its default member (`.Value` in this case).  That means your code is equivalent to:

```
MsgBox dict(Cells(1, 1).Value)
```

For your second example using `temp`, I'm assuming that it is either undeclared (and implicitly `Variant`) or some other strongly typed value.  In that case, the *assignment* is implicitly calling the default member of `Cells(1, 1)`, so your assignment is equivalent to:

```
Dim temp As Variant
temp = Cells(1, 1).Value
dict.Add temp, Cells(1, 2)  '<--- temp is whatever the type of Cells(1, 1).Value is.
```

If temp is declared as a `Range` (or `Object`), it works exactly the same as in `Sub Example()` above:

```
Dim temp As Range
Set temp = Cells(1, 1)
dict.Add temp, Cells(1, 2)    '<--- temp is a Range.
```

Keep in mind that unique cell *values* are different than unique cell *objects*:

```
Public Sub Example2()
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Cells(1, 1).Value = "Foo"
    Cells(1, 2).Value = "Foo"

    'This is fine - the keys are unique cell references:
    dict.Add Cells(1, 1), Empty
    dict.Add Cells(1, 2), Empty   '<-- No runtime error

    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    'This is an error - the keys are identical values:
    dict.Add Cells(1, 1).Value, Empty
    dict.Add Cells(1, 2).Value, Empty  '<-- Runtime error 457, key already exists.
End Sub
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly - because I used the key as one data type when saving it in the dictionary (cell), but it defaults to a different data type when msgbox is called (variant), it doesn't show up, because even though the text is identical, the data type is different?  And thus using temp was a kind of unintentional bridge across that, by unwittingly saving it in the dictionary as a different data type, coincidentally the same one msgbox defaults to?

Comment: @GrahamPerry - No.  It's the same type (`Range`).  You can't `MsgBox` an object, so it calls its default member - `.Value`.  Assigning to `temp` did exactly the same thing because you didn't use `Set` in front of it.  Assignments to `Variant`'s without the `Set` keyword are value assignments, not reference assignments.

Comment: I'm...more confused now, I think.  `Cells(1, 1)` is range object.  temp is a(n undeclared) variant, so it implicitly sets itself equal to `Cells(1, 1).Value`.  And range is an object (?), so msgbox tries to remedy that by adding `.value`, yielding `Cells(1, 1).Value`.   I mean, clearly that isn't the case, because otherwise it would work, because that's the same result, but...

Comment: @GrahamPerry - That's pretty much exactly what happens. Technically it calls `Cells(1, 1).[_Default]`, but that's the same thing as `Cells(1, 1).Value`. This [blog post](http://bytecomb.com/values-and-references-in-vba/) (not mine) might help clarify the concepts at work here.